# How to pass a variable through a segue in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

This is the block of code in my main `UITableViewController` with the class being `InventoryTableViewController`

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)
        switch segue.identifier! {
            case "detailSegue":
                guard let inventoryDetail = segue.destination as? InventoryDetailView else {
                    fatalError("Unexpected destination: \(segue.destination)")
                }
                guard let selectedVehicleCell = sender as? InventoryTableViewCell else {
                    fatalError("Unexpected sender: \(String(describing: sender))")
                }
                guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: selectedVehicleCell) else {
                    fatalError("The selected cell is not being displayed by the table")
                }
                let selectedVehicle = vehicles[indexPath.row]
                inventoryDetail.vehicle = selectedVehicle as? InventoryDetailView.Inventory
                printGenericInfo(selectedVehicle)
                default:
                fatalError("Unexpected Segue Identifier; \(String(describing: segue.identifier))")
        }
   }

   func printGenericInfo<T>(_ value: T) {

        let t = type(of: value as Any)
        print("'\(value)' of type '\(t)'")
   }
```

I am trying to pass selectedVehicle. When I print the value and the type it is as follows (and is correct):

> Inventory(id: 1004, year: "2014", make: "MakeWith15Chars", model:
>   "ModelWith15Char", body: "BodyWith15Chars", interior: "Hickory",
>   exterior: "Magnetic Gray", vin: "2C4RDGCG0FR805928", miles: "10450",
>   msrp: "33,800.00", cost: "28,100.00") of type Inventory

The block of code in my `InventoryDetailView` is as follows:

```
class InventoryDetailView: UIViewController {

    var vehicle: Inventory!
    struct Inventory: Hashable, Codable, Identifiable {
                var id: Int
                var year: String
                var make: String
                var model: String
                var body: String
                var interior: String
                var exterior: String
                var vin: String
                var miles: String
                var msrp: String
                var cost: String
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        yearMakeLabel.text = vehicle?.year
    }
}
```

When I print the value of vehicle in InventoryDetailView is nil. Why? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you connect the segue from the UITableViewCell instead of the UITableView? Could you check which one is called first? `viewDidLoad()` of `InventoryDetailView` or `prepare(for:sender)` of `InventoryTableViewController`.

Comment: The segue is definitely from the UITableViewCell

Comment: Try to remove the segue, and redo it from the `InventoryTableViewController` to `InventoryDetailView` instead.

Comment: The order is prepare(for:sender) first then viewDidLoad()

Comment: I changed the segue. still nil

Comment: What Im doing is displaying a list of vehicles from a simple .json data source. The list is clickable and I need to send the chosen vehicle to the detail view. The segue is working and the detail view comes up but the variable that I'm setting is coming up nil. The original value is set in the TableViewController but is not getting passed properly to the DetailView.

Comment: @BillS - it *sounds* like you have an unrelated issue. Add a new property to `InventoryDetailView` such as `var testString: String!` then in prepare where you are currently doing `inventoryDetail.vehicle = selectedVehicle` ***also*** do `inventoryDetail.testString = "abc"` ... then see if you can set `yearMakeLabel.text = testString`

Comment: @DonMag - I did what you recommended and it worked. When I print testString in the destination it prints Optional("abc"). Also to add something, there is a warning coming up that reads "Coercion of implicitly unwrappable value of type 'String?' to 'Any' does not unwrap optional" and there is a similar warning where Im printing vehicle in the destination "Coercion of implicitly unwrappable value of type 'InventoryDetailView.Inventory?' to 'Any' does not unwrap optional"

Comment: @BillS - well, you have a couple odd things going on... First, you've declared `var vehicle: Inventory!` as non-optional...  do you still get `nil` if you do `yearMakeLabel.text = vehicle.year` (without the **?**)? Also, you are casting `vehicles[indexPath.row]  as? InventoryDetailView.Inventory` ... what is  ``vehicles[indexPath.row] ` to begin with? Also... is there a reason you are using `Inventory` as a class-bound struct instead of defining it outside the class so you can use it in `InventoryTableViewController` ?

Comment: Please bare with my ignorance. vehicles is the full list and vehicles[indexPath.row] is one of the vehicles. The value is what I put in my original question "Inventory(id:..." ... I @DonMag - think the problem ultimately is that the declarations aren't being done correctly. Everything works up until I'm setting the value of a variable to another variable that I want to use in a different class. I'm not really sure how the variable declaration needs to be done?

Comment: @BillS - is your project in a state where you can post it on GitHub so I can take a look at what you're doing? If not, try creating a new project with the bare minimum to reproduce this issue (see [mre]).

Comment: Thank you for all of your help. Your suggestions helped me think through the problem and I came up with a solution. It's not what I really wanted but it works. I still don't understand why the hash variable wasn't being set and passed properly. I'm very new at iOS so I have a lot of growing to do.

Answer (score -1):

I think, first of all, you have to delete this line `super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)` because you don’t need to call it

Comment: I took out that line but it is still coming up nil